# How to execute Microsoft Jet 4.0 SQL commands with JDBC with Microsoft Access

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc

I have Access DB ( mdb file) to which I can connect using my java program. User level security for the Access DB is on. I am trying to add new user in the User level security i.e. MDW file. 
I think this can be done by executing SQL statement = Microsoft Jet 4.0 SQL commands = "CREATE USER Boyd password"

but when i execute it with, it give me error which is as follows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCQuery {
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" + 
                    "Dbq=C:\\Users\\Public\\uls\\ulsTest.mdb;" +
                    "SystemDB=C:\\Users\\Public\\uls\\Security.mdw;" +
                    "Uid=Gord;" +
                    "Pwd=obfuscated;" +
                    "ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            s.execute("CREATE USER Tim pwd");
            System.out.println("User 'Tim' created.");
            s.execute("DROP USER Tim");
            System.out.println("User 'Tim' dropped.");
            s.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Worked like charm. Difference is I was describing connection details without ExtendedAnsiSQl flag.

Comment: It creates the user properly but can not log in into the DB using the new user? What may be problem?